# Dialogflow CX Git Integration in Cloud Source Repositories

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-cx, google-cloud-source-repos

I was trying to enable the Git integration of Dialogflow CX to version the development of an Agent.

My project has been designed to keep all the resources versioning through Cloud Source Repositories. However, from the Dialogflow CX Console it is only possible to enable the Git integration with GitHub repositories.

Is there a way to Add a Git Connection on the base of a Cloud Source Repository or this functionality is only meant for Github?
It seems quite strange that using a Google Cloud product like Dialogflow does not allow to enable the Git versioning through another Google Cloud product like Cloud Source Repositories.

Answer (score 1):

**Dialogflow CX** primarily supported Git integration with GitHub repositories. If you wanted to version your Dialogflow CX Agent using a Google Cloud product like Cloud Source Repositories, you might need to set up a workflow to synchronize changes between a Cloud Source Repository and a GitHub repository.

This might involve using Cloud Build or a similar service to automate the synchronization of code between your Cloud Source Repository and a GitHub repository, which can then be connected to Dialogflow CX for version control.